# Applying CSS classes to table rows with Sphinx and reStructuredText

Tags: python, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

We have a website that is generated using Sphinx and reStructuredText. Albeit not ideal (I have inherited this code), it's something that so far has worked and serves the purpose. We're trying to extend it slightly and one request was to highlight better certain rows in a table based on a condition (just a bit of context).

What we noticed is that if the element that needs the style applied is the first one in the for-loop, the style gets instead applied to the parent (`<tbody>`) element.

This is the relevant piece of code that does not seem to be working as intended:

```
{% for codelist_item in codelist_json.data %}
{% if codelist_item.status == 'withdrawn' %} 
.. rst-class:: withdrawn
* - {{codelist_item.code + " (withdrawn)"}}
    {% else %}
* - {{codelist_item.code}}   
    {% endif %}
  - {{codelist_item.name}}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

NB: indentation is correct (as in it matches what's in our rst file)

Non working example: http://reference.iatistandard.org/202/codelists/BudgetIdentifierVocabulary/

whose HTML is:

```
<tbody class="withdrawn" valign="top">
  <tr class="row-even">
    <td>1 (withdrawn)</td>
    <td>IATI</td>
    <td>The budget identifier reported uses IATI budget identifier categories</td>
  </tr>
```

Working example: http://reference.iatistandard.org/202/codelists/Currency/

```
<tr class="withdrawn row-even">
  <td>BYR (withdrawn)</td>
  <td>Belarussian Ruble</td>
  <td>Withdrawn from ISO Currency codelist. Use code BYN.</td>
</tr>
```

While exploring the Sphinx docs, I stumbled across this bit that might be (or at least sounds) relevant

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#id12

`This allows the "classification" of individual list items (except the first, as a preceding class directive applies to the list as a whole)`

That seems to fit our problem, although like I said I'm not entirely sure it does relate to it.

So far, we tried checking `{% forloop.first %}`, moving the `rst-class::` around, but nothing seems to work.
Any advice?

Comment: I would use pure CSS and the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) of the table row as the selector. Sometimes the programming solution is too complicated.

Comment: The problem is that it have to result in something like (pseudocode-ish) `if the table itself has the style applied, it means its first row (nth-child) needs to be styled` which is as weak as it gets

Comment: It seems you are using a templating system (which?) and also nesting the list in a "list-table" directive (a bullet list would generate `<ul>` and `<li>` elements). Try to create a minimal working example using just rST (it is OK, if the example fails for the right reasons or clearly shows the not-expected behaviour as long as it is easy reproducible).